# How to use flask context with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask

I'm trying to make multiple requests async and get response back, I'm using `concurrent.futures` to do this, but inside my function using `current_app` which from `flask` and I always got this error:

`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

I don't know how to resolve this. Can anyone please help?

Below are my code:

run.py:

```
import concurrent.futures
from flask import current_app
from http_calls import get_price, get_items

def init():
    with current_app._get_current_object().test_request_context():
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
            futs = []
            futs.append(executor.submit(get_price))
            futs.append(executor.submit(get_items))

            print([fut.result() for fut in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futs)])

init()
```

http_calls.py

```
from flask import current_app

def get_price():
    url = current_app.config['get_price_url']
    return requests.get(url).json()

def get_items():
    url = current_app.config['get_items_url']
    return requests.get(url).json()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import your Flask instance in your script. Use `current_app` under the app context.

```
import concurrent.futures
from your_application import your_app  # or create_app function to return a Flask instance
from flask import current_app
from http_calls import get_price, get_items

def init():
    with your_app.app_context():
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
            ...
```

Comment: if i dont use `current_app`, there is no need of using `app_context()` ?

Answer (score 16):

I was running into similar issues around using concurrent.futures with Flask. I wrote [Flask-Executor](https://github.com/dchevell/flask-executor) as a Flask-friendly wrapper for concurrent.futures to solve this problem. It may be an easier way for you to work with these two together.

Comment: This solution worked for me... although it's a shame to see that the code hasn't been maintained in 11 months. You made a great thing @daveruinseverything , I hope to see you continue to support it!